# Why I have NullPointerException here?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have created a class which name is Manager and I have a Frame which name is BirthList and this frame has a table.I work with MySQL and I have entered some data in the "birthtable" in MySQL.and i want to add those data from MySQL table in to the table which is in my frame .
HINT: birthList is a list of Birth objects.
but I will find this exception why?
Please help me:(

Manager class:

```
  public Manager class{
  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
  private static Connection conn = DBManager.getConnection();
  private static Admin admin;

  public static void addToBirthListFromMySQL() throws SQLException {



    try{
      Statement  stmt = conn.createStatement();



     ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM birthtable");

       Birth list1;

        while (rs.next()) {
            String s1 = rs.getString(2);
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                s1 = null;
            }
            String s2 = rs.getString(3);
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                s2 = null;
            }
            String s3 = rs.getString(4);
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                s3 = null;
            }
            String s4 = rs.getString(5);
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                s4 = null;
            }
            String s5 = rs.getString(6);
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                s5 = null;
            }
            String s6 = rs.getString(7);
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                s6 = null;
            }


          list1 = new Birth(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6);
          admin.birthList.add(list1);


        }




    }
    catch(SQLException e){





    }

}
```

My Frame:

```
public class BirthList extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Admin admin;

    /** Creates new form BirthList */
    public BirthList(Admin admin) {
        initComponents();
        this.admin = admin;
        try {
            Manager.addToBirthListFromMySQL();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BirthList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        fillTable();
    }


public void fillTable() {

        String[] columNames = {"name", "family", "father's name", "mother's name", "date of birth", "place of birth"};
        List<Birth> birth = admin.getBirthList();
        Object[][] data = new Object[birth.size()][columNames.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            Birth birth1 = birth.get(i);
            data[i][0] = birth1.getName();
            data[i][1] = birth1.getFamily();
            data[i][2] = birth1.getFatherName();
            data[i][3] = birth1.getMotherName();
            data[i][4] = birth1.getDateOfBirth();
            data[i][5] = birth1.getPlaceOfBirth();


        }
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columNames);
        jTable1.setModel(model);
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

stacktrace:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at database.Manager.addToBirthListFromMySQL(Manager.java:272)
        at AdminGUI.BirthList.(BirthList.java:35)
        at AdminGUI.BirthFrame.newButton1ActionPerformed(BirthFrame.java:127)
        at AdminGUI.BirthFrame.access$000(BirthFrame.java:21)
        at AdminGUI.BirthFrame$1.actionPerformed(BirthFrame.java:58)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3265)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)

**line 272 is :admin.birthList.add(list1);**

**I also debug my project and the result was :

**debug:
Listening on javadebug
User program running
Debugger stopped on uncompilable source code.**

*I also print my object admin with system.out.println(admin) and the result was:

classes.Admin@20be79*

Comment: It would help if we knew what line `Manager.java:272` was.

Comment: Ash is right.
ps And also it seems you do not need list1 variable. You simply could do this:

          admin.birthList.add(new Birth(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6));

Comment: In this case it would help if you could say which is line 272 in the Manager class. As an aside, the try /catch block in addToBirthListFromMySQL() will mask/discard any SQLException that is thrown

Comment: line 272 is "admin.birthList.add(list1);"

Comment: Just added `Manager.admin` initialization step, for avoiding the NPE. See my completed answer

Comment: also it returns NPE for this line:"admin.birthList.add(list1);"

Comment: Should i have write this statement exactly before line 272:
BirthList b = new BirthList(admin);   ?????

Comment: but also when I write the above statement it will show the "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError" !!!! what should I do?

Comment: @Johanna: you do not need to initialize Manager.admin just before line 272, unless some other part of the code reset it back to null. If you have an exception, you need to at least catch it and add the full exception message to your question for us to debug.

Comment: Ok I delete the line which couse stackoverflowexception and also i have send my whole stacktrace above.

Comment: @Johanna: Make sure you are not using the 1.6 compiler and the 1.5 runtime to execute/debug your program.

Comment: @Johanna, see my extended answer on this (JDK6 vs. JRE5)

Comment: @Johanna: could you check what version of Java you are actually using when executing your program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of hunting the root cause in the dark, I think it's better to explain how and why NPE's are caused and how they can be avoided, so that the OP can apply the newly gained knowledge to hunt his/her own trivial problem.

Look, object references (the variables) can contain either a fullworthy `Object` or simply *nothing*, which is `null`.

```
SomeObject someObject1 = new SomeObject(); // References something.
SomeObject someObject2 = null; // References nothing.
```

Now, if you're trying to access *nothing* (`null`), then you will undoubtely get a `NullPointerException`, simply because `null` doesn't have any variables or methods.

```
someObject1.doSomething(); // Works fine.
someObject2.doSomething(); // Throws NullPointerException.
```

Workarounding this is fairly simple. It can be done in basically two ways: either by instantiating it or just by ignoring it.

```
if (someObject2 == null) {
    someObject2 = new SomeObject();
}
someObject2.doSomething(); // No NPE anymore!
```

or

```
if (someObject2 != null) {
    someObject2.doSomething(); // No NPE anymore!
}
```

In case of a NPE, the first line number of the stacktrace points the exact line where the it is been caused. You told literally "line 272 is `admin.birthList.add(list1);`". This line contains **two** places where object references are been accessed/invoked (using the dot `.` operator). The first being `admin.birthList` and the second being `birthList.add(list1)`. It's up to you to find out if one or both caused the NPE. If it is the first invocation, then `admin` is simply `null`. If it is the second invocation, then `birthList` is simply `null`. You can fix it by instantiating it with a fullworthy object.

**Edit:** If you have a hard time in determining the root cause (as turns out from comments), then you need to learn debugging. Run a debugger or just do "poor man's debugging" with help of a `System.out.println()` of every variable before accessing/invoking them. First look at line where the NPE is caused. If this is for example

```
admin.birthList.add(list1);
```

then you need to change it as follows to nail down the root cause:

```
System.out.println("admin: " + admin);
List<Birth> birthList = admin.birthList;
System.out.println("birthList: " + birthList);
birthList.add(list1);
```

check if any of them prints `null`. Alternatively you can also do:

```
if (admin == null) throw new NullPointerException("admin is null!");
List<Birth> birthList = admin.birthList;
if (birthList == null) throw new NullPointerException("birthList is null!");
birthList.add(list1);
```

you can also separate the individual invocations over separate lines so that you have enough to the line number to know which reference is null.

```
List<Birth> birthList = admin.birthList; // If NPE line points here, then admin is null.
birthList.add(list1); // If NPE line points here, then birthList is null.
```

Comment: I have done what ever you told me but I still have NPE:(((((((((

Comment: also i found that my birthList is null not my admin object ,also I have done  if(admin==null&& birthList==null){
                  admin = new Admin();
                  birthList = new ArrayList<Birth>();
              }
              else{
                 admin.birthList.add(list1);
              }
but still I have NPE:((((((((

Comment: +1 for the effort, the details about NPE and for the "Then learn debugging" comment ;)

Comment: wow,thanks a lot I found that birthList is null and I solve that,thanks a million :">

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, I would say your `Admin` instance is null, causing the NPE in the `addToBirthListFromMySQL()` method

```
public BirthList(Admin admin) {
        initComponents(); // where do you set this.admin to the parameter 'admin' ?
```

You also need to initialize the static variable `admin` of your static object `Manager`

```
public BirthList(Admin admin) {
        this.admin = admin
        Manager.admin = admin
        initComponents();
```

(note: you may want to not call your parameter with the same name than internal variables)

---

> **I also debug my project and the result was** :

```
debug: Have no FileObject for C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar

Have no FileObject for C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02\jre\classes**
```

**Make sure you are not using the 1.6 compiler and the 1.5 runtime to execute/debug your program.**

See [this thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5306288):

> Here is a list of possibilities for future users:
>
> 1. Committed to the Repository.  (probably not)
> 2. Re-Set all of my responsible environment variables...
>      a. `set path="D:\...\JDK1.5\bin"`
>      b. `set classpath="D:\...\JDK1.5\bin"`
>      c. `set java_home="D:\...\JDK1.5"`
> 3. Re-set all of my Dependencies on my project.  (`Project Properties->Libraries`).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell because the line numbers in the stack trace don't seem to match your code, but do you ever set the "private static Admin admin;" variable in Manager to a non-null value?

Answer (score 0):

If line 272 of `Manager.java` is:

```
admin.birthList.add(list1);
```

and if `admin` is not `null` which is my understanding of your updates, then the conclusion seems pretty obvious: `birthlist` is `null` and the code breaks when you call the `add()` method on it.

My guess is that your `Admin` class looks something like this:

```
public class Admin {
    public List<Birth> birthList; //the visibility seems to be public
    ...
}
```

and you never initialize the `birthList` class attribute. So either initialize it inline, in the constructor, in an `init()` method, etc but do it somewhere. For example, inline:

```
public class Admin {
    public List<Birth> birthList = new ArrayList<Birth>(); 
    ...
}
```

Actually, I'm not sure how you instantiate and set the `Admin` static instance of your `Manager` class but this is another story.