# Why does this code throw a java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-2d

I have found a source code and i added it to my frame just for testing which it uses Java2D.
But it thows an exception. I don't understand why.

my class:

```
package ClientGUI;




import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

/**
 *
 * @author ICC
 */

public class SignInFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable {

private static int iw,  ih,  iw2,  ih2;
private static Image img;
private static final int FORWARD = 0;
private static final int BACK = 1;

// the points of the curve
private Point2D pts[];

// initializes direction of movement forward, or left-to-right
private int direction = FORWARD;
private int pNum;
private int x,  y;
private Thread thread;
private BufferedImage bimg;

/** Creates new form SignInFrame */
public SignInFrame() {
    initComponents();
    img = getToolkit().getImage(Image.class.getResource("Yahoo-Messanger.jpg"));
    try {
        MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(this);
        tracker.addImage(img, 0);
        tracker.waitForID(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    iw = img.getWidth(this);
    ih = img.getHeight(this);
    iw2 = iw / 2;
    ih2 = ih / 2;

}

public void reset(int w, int h) {
    pNum = 0;
    direction = FORWARD;

    // initializes the cubic curve
    CubicCurve2D cc = new CubicCurve2D.Float(
            w * .2f, h * .5f, w * .4f, 0, w * .6f, h, w * .8f, h * .5f);

    // creates an iterator to define the boundary of the flattened curve
    PathIterator pi = cc.getPathIterator(null, 0.1);
    Point2D tmp[] = new Point2D[200];
    int i = 0;

    // while pi is iterating the curve, adds points to tmp array
    while (!pi.isDone()) {
        float[] coords = new float[6];
        switch (pi.currentSegment(coords)) {
            case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
            case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                tmp[i] = new Point2D.Float(coords[0], coords[1]);
        }
        i++;
        pi.next();
    }
    pts = new Point2D[i];

    // copies points from tmp to pts
    System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, pts, 0, i);
}

public void step(int w, int h) {
    if (pts == null) {
        return;
    }
    x = (int) pts[pNum].getX();
    y = (int) pts[pNum].getY();
    if (direction == FORWARD) {
        if (++pNum == pts.length) {
            direction = BACK;
        }
    }
    if (direction == BACK) {
        if (--pNum == 0) {
            direction = FORWARD;
        }
    }
}

public void drawDemo(int w, int h, Graphics2D g2) {
    g2.drawImage(img,
            0, 0, x, y,
            0, 0, iw2, ih2,
            this);
    g2.drawImage(img,
            x, 0, w, y,
            iw2, 0, iw, ih2,
            this);
    g2.drawImage(img,
            0, y, x, h,
            0, ih2, iw2, ih,
            this);
    g2.drawImage(img,
            x, y, w, h,
            iw2, ih2, iw, ih,
            this);
}

public Graphics2D createGraphics2D(int w, int h) {
    Graphics2D g2 = null;
    if (bimg == null || bimg.getWidth() != w || bimg.getHeight() != h) {
        bimg = (BufferedImage) createImage(w, h);
        reset(w, h);
    }
    g2 = bimg.createGraphics();
    g2.setBackground(getBackground());
    g2.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    return g2;
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Dimension d = getSize();
    step(d.width, d.height);
    Graphics2D g2 = createGraphics2D(d.width, d.height);
    drawDemo(d.width, d.height, g2);
    g2.dispose();
    g.drawImage(bimg, 0, 0, this);
}

public void start() {
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    thread = null;
}

public static void main(String argv[]) {

    SignInFrame f = new SignInFrame();





    f.start();
}

public void run() {

    Thread me = Thread.currentThread();
    while (thread == me) {
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
    thread = null;
}}
```

the exception:

```
  init:
  deps-jar:
  Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\ICC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\YahooServer\build\classes
  compile-single:
  run-single:
  Uncaught error fetching image:
  java.lang.NullPointerException
          at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(URLImageSource.java:97)
          at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(URLImageSource.java:107)
          at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:240)
          at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:172)
          at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:136)
```

Comment: So some unspecified code is being called in an unspecified way and it is erroring. Since we can't see the code, we can't say why.

Comment: You'd make things easier if you'd supply the stack trace or at least the line that causes the NullPointer.

Comment: Sorry ,my net had a problem,I have posted it.

Comment: Exceptions are almost never returned, they are usually thrown! Big difference! While technically you could return an Exception, I've never seen it done in serious code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The offending line is here
`img = getToolkit().getImage(Image.class.getResource("Yahoo-Messanger.jpg"));`
Make sure that the file exists refer to this doc to see the order on how the resources are loaded
[Java Doc for getResource](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String))

Comment: "Messanger" in the line Greg highlighted is misspelled, that might be a possible cause for it failing to find the image.

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(URLImageSource.java:97)
```

I do a wild guess: the URL is null. You need to debug the variables which were used around the time that **your own** code appears for the first time in the stacktrace. I've already [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892851/why-i-have-nullpointerexception-here/1893300#1893300) in one of your previous topics how to debug.

Comment: I think a null url is very likely the cause. Look at the code for URLImageSource.getConnection(): http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/awt/image/URLImageSource.java.html I think there's a good chance that the getResource() call that UmYeah mentions is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use your debugger and define a breakpoint so that your application stops when the NPE is thrown. Then you'll find the line of code where you have a null reference which causes trouble. (or set the breakpoint on the line of code that is printed on the stack trace)

<strike>It's nearly impossible to give more detailed help without seeing the part of the code that throws the exception.</strike>

**Edit**

Simple typo this time? Is the image file called `Yahoo-Messanger.jpg` or shouldn't it be `Yahoo-Messenger.jpg` instead? Could be that you can't find the image. Unfortunatly your stacktrace snippet doesn't include the line of code in your class where the trouble starts.

Comment: Having had this same error, the stack trace doesn't actually contain a line of custom code. Nor can you catch the exception yourself and mitigate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I find the best way to solve these problems is one step at a time. The exception states that there was an error fetching the image. In `SignInFrame()` you are trying to retrieve an image `img = getToolkit().getImage(Image.class.getResource("Yahoo-Messanger.jpg"));`

Make sure that you are pointing to the image correctly. It may also help to look at the [javadoc for getResource](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

Also, I think (and im no expert) that it is generally a good idea to put methods that may throw exception in a try-catch. This way you know exactly where the error happens when the exception is throw.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you call f.start() it will actually invoke the run() method and not your own start() method, since the class implements Runnable.

Answer (score 0):

the question is already answered, but I would suggested two additional changes in this line:

```
    img = getToolkit().getImage(Image.class.getResource("Yahoo-Messanger.jpg"));
```

1 - check the returned URL, it will be `null` if the image was not found.

2 - I think that `Image.class` is misleading here. Use `getClass()` as there is no (apparent) reason to use the Classloader of the Image class.

```
    URL url = getClass().getResource("Yahoo-Messanger.jpg");
    if (url == null) {
        // some error handling here: throw an Exception, logging, ...
    }
    img = getToolkit().getImage(url);
```

throwing an Exception would be the best solution IMHO.