# NullPointerException for images when running in command prompt

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, embedded-resource, imageicon

I'm having a `NullPointerException`  when I compile my code but it works fine in eclipse.

Error log from command prompt:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(Unknown Source)
```

The class getting the images is:

```
package tileGame;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


public class Image {


public String address1;
public String address2;
public String name;
public String type;

public java.awt.Image image;

public Image(String name){
    address1 = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    address2 = "/Resources/Images/";
    type = "png";
    this.name = name;
}
public Image(String name, String type){
    address1 = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    address2 = "/src/Resources/Images/";
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
}
public Image(String name, String type, String address){
    address1 = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    this.address2 = address;
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
}
public void loadImage(){
    //image = new ImageIcon(address1 + address2 + name + "." + type).getImage();
    image = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource(address2 + name + "." + type))).getImage();
    System.out.println("Image Loaded '" + name + "' at '" + address2 + name + "." + type + "'");
}
```

}

There is probably a good reason for this that I can't see as I am fairly new to Java so if anyone could give me some pointers then that would be welcome.

Edit: OK I fixed it just common human error that I wouldn't have spotted on my own. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like your Image isn't where you think it is.

Comment: @nachokk obviously runtime , its NullPointerException

Comment: @anshulkatta i know , but the name of the title is when compiled :D, it sounds strange

Comment: @nachokk oh ok , i have edited  :P

Comment: I think he means when he runs from the command line versus his IDE.  If that's so, I suspect the problem is that the system property "user.dir" is pointing to different locations in those two cases.

Comment: Study the examples cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).

Answer (score 3):

`getClass().getResource(path)` accesses a resource "file" in the class path (read-only). If the application is compiled, this file resides inside the jar. With 7zip or WinZip you might look inside the jar and find the path.

The path uses as any URL `/` as path separator.
The path can be relative to the class (remember `getClass()`), that is the package path.
The path can also be absolute to the jar's root: "/...".

Furthermore the path must be case-sensitive, not as Windows file paths.

In your case no need for any system property to get a file system path.

Comment: OK my bad it turns out that it was the case sensitive thing, I had changed the names of the files since the creation of the class and not fixed it as it still worked in eclipse so I didn't fix it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of relative-path issue. `java.exe` is starting from different directories in eclipse and command prompt.

To make sure that it works:

1. Use absolute path (to confirm the issue)
2. When running the program use `-cp` and add the necessary directories to `classpath`.

Answer (score 0):

This class has no compilation failures (apart from the missing final `}`)

What you are having is a problem when **running** your code. You are probably having the same issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021011/why-does-this-code-throw-a-java-lang-nullpointerexception) and it is probably in the `getClass().getResource(address2 + name + "." + type)`.

Reading resources from the classpath is tricky because you don get exceptions when you dont find them, you instead get `null`. Also when reading from the classpath you have to be careful if you are using a class or a classloader as paths change. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)